# UIPageControl require XIB?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, xib, uipagecontrol

All the examples I've seen for PageControl has used XIBs to switch between views when you scroll. Is this a requirement? Is it possible to load another viewController in Storyboard for the PageControl? I tried doing it, but no success. It does not load the ViewController. I was told to use initWithCoder to load Views from the Storyboard. I have no idea what to put in the initWithCoder and the documentation on Apple Dev on initWithCoder and Coders are confusing.

I could only get paging to work with XIBs.

Update:
So more specifically, the paging works fine, but I am asking when I make a ViewController class that manages one of the paged Views. How do I get the class to load the View from Storyboard? I could only get the view to load when using a XIB.

Thanks,
Alan

Comment: Show your code. Where the views come from ands how to use a page control to switch between them is completely independent from each other.

Comment: Okay, well I am using Apple's example on Page Control, so the Paging works fine. I am just not sure how to load the View from Storyboard... I can only get the views to load properly using LoadWithXib.